# Closed form solution for a nested recurrent expression

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am struggling with a (probably) trivial series that goes as:

$x(1+y(x(1+y(x(1+y(x....)$

If I infer it correctly, it seems like:

$x(1+xy+x^2y^2+\ldots+\infty)$

How do I get a closed form solution for this? I am really bad with understanding series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let the series be $S$.
$x(1+yS)=S$
$x+xyS=S$
$x=S(1-xy)$
$S=\frac{x}{1-xy}$

the second expression you have written is a geometric series.

Comment: Thanks! But what is this called exactly?

Comment: How did you come up with the identity $x(1+yS)=S$ after setting the series equal to $S$?